# Why is this REGEX matching this pattern?

Tags: regex, intellij-idea

I do not understand why my pattern is matching certain strings in IntelliJ's find/replace.

I'm putting together a selection of REGEX patterns useful to find/replace certain coding standards, such as flipping null-checks to have null on the left side. In this case, I'm trying to setup an isEmpty converter that recognizes .size or .length comparisons to 0, as in `if(foo.size() == 0)` or `if(zig.zag().length == 0)`

However, my pattern

```
((?:\w+\(?\)?\.)+)\blength\(?\)?|\bsize\(\) ?== ?0
```

is matching to `foo.length` as in

```
for(int i=0; i<foo.length; i++)
```

I would like this pattern to match to empty-string/-collection checks such as `foo.length == 0` or `bar.size() == 0` in order to convert them to use isEmpty() (i.e. `foo.isEmpty()`). But not to match other cases, such as the case above. I would also like this REGEX to be useful for both empty string *and* empty collection checks.

Comment: Java strings don't have a `size()` method, but collections do.  Please cleanup your question and make it clear exactly which code you are trying to find and replace.

Comment: I left it vague because I wanted the regex to match both empty string _and_ empty collection checks.

Comment: That's not going to work very well for your question.  Please narrow it down.

Comment: You used a backslash before the space following the `==`, I don't know how that will behave, but it is not necessary.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I edited the question according to your advice; is it more clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `|` operator has *very* low precedence, you should put parentheses around `length|size\(\)`:

```
(\w*\.)+\b(length|size\(\)) ?== ?0
```

Comment: The `|` operator in this case is a regex alternation (OR), _not_ a logical OR.  So precedence doesn't mean the same thing here.

Comment: yes, but the expression he has is looking either for something like `foo.length` OR for something like `size() == 0`

Comment: @TallChuck I updated the REGEX pattern in the original question to closer resemble the final pattern while retaining the initial problem; you'll probably want to update your answer accordingly.

Comment: I'm happy to leave it as it is, it gets the point across without too many extra characters